# what's the difference between ./script.sh and bash script.sh

Tags: linux, bash

On linux system, is there any difference to kick of script.sh in these two different ways?

Are they exactly the same thing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bash nubie, but one difference I know of is that environment variables have local scope when executing a script, but sourcing a script adds any definitions to the parent scope

Comment: @DeepYellow: sourcing a script happens when issuing the commands `source script.sh` or `. script.sh`

Comment: @DeepYellow: yeah, but the question has nothing to do with sourcing scripts. As such your comment is slightly confusing and misleading.

Comment: @knittl You're right!  I misread, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

./script.sh expects that this file is in the current directory, has execute bit set and the first line of the file is path to the interpreter to start with ( Shebang line )

bash script.sh means that you invoke bash and pass the contents of the file to be executed(interpreted) as bash commands. This way your file doesn't need to be executable and has a shebang line.

If the conditions for ./script.sh are met then both invocations lead to the same result.

Comment: The shebang is not mandatory in most environments (sh is assumed by default)

Answer (score 1):

In order for the first form to work, the file must have the executable bit set, secondly it needs to have a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) which specifies which interpreter that will be used.

So yes, both forms are identical (when it comes to what will be interpreted).

For a history-lesson see [this](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/)

Current implementation of the she-bang parsing in the linux-kernel can be found [here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=fs/binfmt_script.c;h=d3b8c1f6315554df64d3491b52d83d2a73f4a359;hb=28a33cbc24e4256c143dce96c7d93bf423229f92)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is exactly the same.

As far as I understand, you simply execute a script with `./script.sh` on the *current* shell. It hasn't to be a bash (Bourne Again SHell) you're running, it can be any shell installed on your system.

If you execute a script with `bash script.sh`, you tell the system that you want the script to be executed explicitly with a bash shell.

You can see which shells are available for your system by calling:

```
$ cat /etc/shells 
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
```

Comment: `./script.sh` starts a new sub-shell, i.e. the script is not run in the current shell. The actual sub-shell is determined by the shebang (`#!`) line. If no shebang line is contained within the file, default seems to be `sh`

Answer (score 0):

script.sh can be called script.anything as pointed on on the knittl post within bully, the script is identified by

```
#!/whatever/it/is
```

running 
bash ./script.something means your telling it to execute the script using bash and this can return errors rather than run also bully forgot

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

so you could have a perl script called script.sh

```
 cat perl.sh 
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Hello World\n";
:~/Documents$ ./perl.sh 
Hello World

~/Documents$ bash ./perl.sh 
Warning: unknown mime-type for "Hello World\n" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "Hello World\n"
```

Answer (score -2):

Is not necessarily  the same.

If you run script.sh linux will search on the directories set in the $PATH env variable.

With ./script.sh, linux will run the script located on the directory where you are at the moment of the call.

Comment: While this is correct, it does not really answer the OPs question. Nowhere did they ask what happens when they use the file name on its own.

Comment: Hmm you are right, I misunderstood the question.  Thanks for the clarification